# How to redirect URL

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, redirect

How to redirect url 
from

`www.example.com/file.html`

to

`www.example.com/folder/file.html`

using `.htaccess` and `web.config`

I have been searching for hours and have found several topics but none works for us

Comment: Sooo, should it be for apache or for IIS? You should decide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS:

Open web.config in the directory where the old page resides. Then add code in `web.config` there for the old location path and new destination as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="file.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="www.example.com/folder/file.html" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>  
</configuration>
```

For apache:

Add in `.htaccess` the following line:

```
Redirect /file.html http://example.com/folder/file.html
```